# Dynamic PHP Variable not working with PHP function move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, variables, post, image-processing, dynamic

I have a drop down box with multiple options, and based on what value is selected I want it to dynamically update the folder path of the `move_uploaded_file()` function.

When I echo out the same thing that is in the `if($file_name)` block it shows the correct path each time I pick from the drop down, but when I actually submit the image upload the variable is basically empty and uploads the image to `../www/html//$file_name`

Any help on to why the variable is basically empty on submit would be greatly appreciated. I can share all of the code if needed, but all of the rest of it is working fine, even the echo statement is pulling in the variable `$selected` just fine, but just not in the `if($file_name)` block.

```
$selected = $_POST['countries'];

if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])){
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if($file_name) {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, "../www/html/$selected/$file_name");

    }
}

echo "../www/html/$selected/$file_name";
```

Comment: Does `../www/html/$selected/` folder exist? If not, maybe you will have to use a `mkdir` before moving the file.

Comment: Have you correctly set the path? What permissions exist on `$selected`?

Comment: Yes, all cases of the $selected variable have corresponding folders with correct permissions 775. It basically thinks the $selected variable is empty but only in the move_uploaded_file function, everywhere is it shows it correctly everytime an option is selected from the drop down. If I hard code the path it uploads fine, just not with the dynamic variable.

Comment: Here is a google drive link to view the entire code base for it.                         https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBHkSo-XfO3blAtaXlyVGxZcnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I was testing on that last one, here is the most upto date code base   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBHkSo-XfO3bml0amVLQnExQU0/view?usp=sharing